# How do you add scroll bars when window's width is reduced

Tags: css, html5, browsers

I have completed a login webpage, which gets distorted when the browser is narrow.
I added `min-width` property to my body tag, but this does not help.

1. How can I keep all the contents fixed when the webpage is narrow? I don't mind having scroll bar.
2. What is causing this problem?  Is it related to different browsers?
3. Can using some form building application help overcome this issue.

Comment: you have to design your page for responsive. convert your css to responsive!

Comment: Can you share some links for responsive css

Comment: Lets say you have margin 200px in large, you can make it small like this: `@media screen (max-height:500px){ #yourElem{margin-top: 10px} }`

Comment: This question appears to be [off-topic](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) because it's in regards to programming, which is better suited for [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/). You might ask this over there, however be sure to search for similar questions first and read their FAQ.